# How to make regular expression to match this string?

Tags: php, regex

I want to make regular expression to the following string :

**2004 aston....martin db9 31 m3.img**

I want the pattern to match all the spaces and dots except the last dot **(for the extension )** 
i did the following pattern

```
/\s{1,}|\.{1,}/
```

this pattern match all dots and spaces including the last dot how can i exclude the last dot from the string

Ok here is the code also ( PHP )

```
$file = "2004 aston....martin db9 31 m3.img";

echo preg_replace("/\s{1,}|\.{1,}/", "_", $file);
```

and the output is

```
2004_aston_martin_db9_31_m3_img
```

Comment: Ok I added the code also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is equivalent to `/\s+|\.+/`

If you can use lookaheads, then you can do something like that:

```
/(\s+|\.+)(?=.*\.)/
```

Comment: Sorry but that only match the first space, i want all spaces and dots except last dot

Comment: Thats a different expression. Yours would also put a series of spaces and dots into one match, the one of the OP will only match series of only whitespace or only dots.

Comment: You probably stop at the first match. You need keep matching. If you have specified the language you are using I could have been more helpful.

Comment: the ouput will be now `2004_aston_martin_db9_31_m3.img`

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression:

```
\.(?=.*\.)|\s
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers will lead to backtracking by the regex engine.

You should avoid .*

```
(?=.*\.) should be converted to (?=[^.]*\.)
```